# textarea onchange not firing within php script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php page with a form that has a textarea input object. The onchange isn't firing and I can't work out why - it should be so simple! I read through many similar questions online, and I tried adding onkey, onblur, and addEventListener (as per the example below), none of which worked.

But then I discovered that my code works fine in a html page but not in a php page. Is there something about php that makes this event fire differently?

Thanks!

```
<textarea name="Address" ID="Address" onChange="alert('You just changed the textarea.')">xxx</textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
Address.addEventListener('input', () => {
    console.log("You just changed the textarea.");
}, false);

</script>
```

Comment: you should try excluding the script to the PHP by putting it after the PHP closing tag

Comment: my code isn't enclosed by the php tags

Comment: your code seems to work tho https://jsfiddle.net/hzuft9k1/

Comment: yes, it works okay in a html page but not as a php page ...for some reason.

Comment: still works even I tried in a php file

Answer (score 2):

Your code have error "Address" on `Address.addEventListener(...)`, because `Address` is not an object. You need to replace the line:
`Address.addEventListener('input', () => {`
to
`document.getElementById('Address').addEventListener('input', () => {`

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work for me. I tried all sorts of variations on the syntax to see if something would at least give me a hint as to what's happening but...nothing.

Comment: I should add that this works fine on with input type of 'text' but not in textarea. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: @Len I tested with your code above (using textarea) with replaced line and it works, do you mean input type='text' not working?

Comment: No, type='text' is working for me but not textarea. Interesting that it's working for you. I really can't think of any reason why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `onchange` to onkeyup and will work as you expected:

```html
<textarea name="Address" ID="Address" onkeyup="alert('You just changed the textarea.')">xxx</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, but onkeyup didn't work for me either. I think there's something else going on with my script but can't identify what...

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what was causing the issue. There was a plug-in using the textarea object elsewhere in the app that was effecting any change events.

Many thanks to everyone who took the time to reply. Much appreciated!